# YQL - CDATA ]]> error when selecting data using YQL

Tags: web-scraping, yahoo, yql

Trying to scrape data from totalfilm.com using YQL but I'm getting a strange error:

> "The character sequence "]]>" must not appear in content unless used to mark the end of a CDATA section."

```
select * from html where url="www.totalfilm.com"
```

[link](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url=%22http://www.totalfilm.com/reviews/search?term=dog%22)

Comment: Your query works fine for me, and the error is very self-explanatory: what question would you like answered?

Comment: Sorry, the question is how can i scrape data from totalfilm.com using YQL?

Comment: Aha, now it gives the same error as in the question. Unless you're willing to tidy up the HTML yourself (in YQL or elsewhere) or get Total Film to fix it, there might not be a quick answer.

Comment: I'm doing it with php and a html parsing library now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, some fudging may need to occur to get the broken XHTML working as you would like.

Here is a quick, **very crude** [open data table](http://www.datatables.org/) for you which strips any `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` from an (X)HTML page (and also [Tidys](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) it), before applying an optional XPath expression, as in the normal `html` table, to get at the data you need.

You can use it like:

```
use "https://github.com/salathe/yql-tables/raw/examples/data/nocdata.xml" as html;
select * from html where url="www.totalfilm.com"
```